# Adequate and understandable documentation

Tags: janusgraph

I'm currently learning JanusGraph. I ran into the problem of finding normal documentation. On the official website of the project (https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.2/index.html) some items have been omitted, some are fragmentary, some are in the old versions of the documentation, but not in the new 0.3.0. Can anyone give a link to a guide in which all aspects of working with a Janusgraph are clearly and normally described with a JavaApi description: connecting to a gremlin server, creating a graph, configuring and deleting a graph, adding and deleting vertices, which class is responsible for what and much other. I'm already tired of searching Google.